# Can one prove, using the completeness axiom, that the rational numbers are not open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, axioms

It's clear to me that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ just by taking open balls, however a homework problem that I'm looking at makes the following statement "We know that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not open, by the completeness axiom." This is where I am stuck. Is this statement true in that this property is by the completeness axiom? I'm struggling to see how the completeness axiom by itself can imply anything about openness.

Comment: That does seem like an odd statement.  Could you provide the full context of the homework problem?  It might make more sense in context...

Comment: "We know that Q ⊆ R is not open, by the completeness axiom. The next best thing we might ask
is whether Q can be written as a countable intersection of open sets (which may not be open)." (They go on to ask us to prove that there does not exist such a collection of open sets)

Comment: Perhaps it simply means that (by construction, by definition) every real is the limit of rationals, and as there are cuts which correspond to no rational (i.e. irrationals exist), the result ~follows. (That shows they're not closed. "Not open" would follow from: every interval (p, q) with rational p, q contains an irrational, which again completeness can be used to confirm.)

Comment: @BrianO: That would say the rationals are not closed; proving the rationals are not open is more involved.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Aye. Probably the same techniques, but can only guess just what those might be w/o knowing more context.

Comment: If this helps for at all, this is for a second year "Multivariable Calculus" course intended for students who did not take Analysis.

Comment: All you might want the completeness axiom for in this case is to prove the existence of one irrational number $x$.  You know that $0$ is rational.  If $\mathbb Q$ was open, there would be some $\epsilon > 0$ such that every real $x$ with  $|x - 0| < \epsilon$ is rational.  But if $n > |x|/\epsilon$, the fact that $x/n$ is irrational contradicts this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: That argument also implicitly uses the completeness axiom in a complicated way to prove that such an $n$ exists.  Although I suppose that if you assume no such $n$ exists, you can get an even simpler argument that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open (some interval around $0$ would contain no rationals besides $0$).

Answer (score 3):

If your definition of the reals is "a complete ordered field", then of course in some sense the completeness axiom is what guarantees that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$: if you only knew that $\mathbb{R}$ was an ordered field, it could be that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}$.  So, any proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ will have to use the completeness axiom somewhere.  But you're right that it's not in any way an *immediate* consequence of the completeness axiom.

In contrast, the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not *closed* in $\mathbb{R}$ is more or less an immediate consequence of the completeness axiom, as indicated in BrianO's comment.  I'm guessing that whoever wrote your homework problem actually had this fact in mind, and was just attempting to provide some (kind of feeble) motivation behind the homework problem without realizing that what they were saying didn't really make sense.

Comment: It's goofy but not that bad: it suffices to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ contains no neighborhood of $0$, and then, it's enough to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there's an irrational in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. So let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be large enough that $ 0 < \frac {\sqrt 2} n < \epsilon$ (because Archimedes). Existence of $\sqrt 2$ follows from the completeness axiom :) and irrationality of $\frac {\sqrt 2} n$ is routine.

Answer (score 0):

A thought: (possibly invalid, depending on the definitions used)

This is equivalent to showing that the irrationals form a closed set. This is false because the set
$$ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \supset A = \{ -2^{1/2-n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$
has least upper bound $0$, and $A$ ordered using the real total order forms a Cauchy sequence that approaches $0$, so there is a Cauchy sequence of irrationals converging to a rational, so the rationals aren't closed.